# Solving Optimal Control with Fixed-end-point with Gekko

Tags: python, gekko

I wanna solve an optimal control problem with the fixed-end-point condition on state variables in Gekko.  I like to know how it is possible to define an optimal control problem with fixed-end-point as follows in Gekko:

```
$\min \int_{0}^{1} u^2+(u-x)^2 $

$\dot{x}=x+u$

$x(0)=1$

$x(1)=4$
```

Moreover, how can I retrieve the objective function value?

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve the objective function value with `m.options.OBJFCNVAL`. Here is a similar script to some of the [Benchmark problems](https://apmonitor.com/do/index.php/Main/DynamicOptimizationBenchmarks) (see 1b in particular).

[image: Optimization solution]

```py
import numpy as np
from gekko import GEKKO
m = GEKKO()
nt = 101; m.time = np.linspace(0,1,nt)
x = m.Var(1)
u = m.Var()
p = np.zeros(nt); p[-1] = 1.0; final = m.Param(value=p)
m.Equation(x.dt()==x+u)
m.Equation(final*(x-4)==0)
m.Minimize(m.integral(u**2+(u-x)**2)*final)

m.options.IMODE = 6; m.solve()
print('Objective: ' + str(m.options.OBJFCNVAL))

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot(m.time,x.value,'k:',LineWidth=2,label=r'$x$')
plt.plot(m.time,u.value,'b--',LineWidth=2,label=r'$u$')
plt.legend(loc='best'); plt.xlabel('Time')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thank you @John. I used your code in another similar problem with the objective function `integral(u**2)` and terminal condition `x(1)=0`, but its result is different from the analytical solution based on Pontryagin's Maximum Principle.

Comment: Dear @John. I have changed the initial value of control and set it to the optimal initial control and it could find the optimal solution. But, I knew the optimal solution while in real-worl problem it is not possible. Could you please let me know how I can overcome this issue? Thanks

Comment: It sounds like your problem is non-convex if the solver finds a different solution based on the initial conditions. You may also need to check that the solver reported a successful solution with `m.options.APPSTATUS`. I recommend variable bounds or multi-start methods if your problem is non-convex.

Comment: Please add the code to another post if you'd like help with the non-convex problem that also has an analytical solution. There are more example problems here that may also serve as an inspiration for your problem: https://apmonitor.com/do/index.php/Main/MoreDynamicOptimizationBenchmarks